# How to a break down a str into a list?

Tags: python, tkinter

rookie question here but I am making a very basic program with a GUI. It takes French words and translates them to English (sort of)

```
from tkinter import *
import webbrowser
def show_entry_fields():
    website = "www.wordreference.com/fren/%s" % (e1.get())
    webbrowser.open(website)

master = Tk()
Label(master, text="French Word").grid(row=0)

e1 = Entry(master)

e1.grid(row=0, column=1)

Button(master, text='Quit', command=master.quit).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)
Button(master, text='Show', command=show_entry_fields).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)

mainloop( )
```

Problem is, if I type in multiple words, it opens up

```
www.wordreference.com/fren/Bonjour%20Avoir
```

I have tried

```
e1 = [Entry(master)]
```

But that gives me errors, as does

```
e1 = Entry[(master)]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change `show_entry_fields` and use `str`'s [`split()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
def show_entry_fields():
    # assuming the words are separated by one or more spaces
    word_list = e1.get().split()  # break the content of e1 into a list of words
    for word in word_list:
        website = "www.wordreference.com/fren/%s" % word
        webbrowser.open(website)
```

If you want the words to be separated by something other than spaces, then you need to pass the delimiter to `split`. For example, if the words are separated by a comma followed by a space (as in `'hello, world, bye'`), then the `split` call should be `word_list = e1.get().split(', ')`.

---

As for the errors you get, `e1 = [Entry(master)]` makes `e1` a list, which doesn't have a `get()` method. So you get an `AttributeError` when you call `show_entry_fields`. `e1 = Entry[(master)]` does not make an `Entry` instance but is trying to index into `Entry` (the class) which isn't the kind of thing you can index into. So this should immediately raise a `TypeError`.